# AVL trees insertion and deletion

Tags: data-structures, tree, tree-rotation

I would like to know whether I am applying the following insertion and deletion operations correctly on an AVL tree:

```
                           62
                          /  \
                        44    78
                       /  \     \
                     17    50    88
                          /  \
                        48    54
```

- insert(42)
- insert(90)
- delete(62)
- insert(92)
- delete(50)

For this question, a deletion replaces the deleted item with its *successor*.

This is how I think the tree should be modified by those operations:

**insert(42) and insert(90)**

```
                           62
                          /  \
                        44    78
                       /  \     \
                     17    50    88
                       \   /  \    \
                       42 48  54    90
```

**delete(62)**

```
                           78
                          /  \
                        44    88
                       /  \     \
                     17    50    90
                       \   /  \    
                       42 48  54
```

**insert(92)**

```
                           78
                          /  \
                        44    88
                       /  \     \
                     17    50    90
                       \   /  \    \  
                       42 48  54    92
```

**delete(50)**

```
                           78
                          /  \
                        44    88
                       /  \     \
                     17    54    90
                       \   /       \  
                       42 48        92
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a two cases where rotations are needed:

```
                         ___62___
                        /        \
                     __44__      78
                    /      \       \
                   17      50      88
                          /  \
                         48  54
```

You had applied `insert(42)` correctly, but `insert(90)` creates an unbalanced subtree rooted at 78 (marked with asterisk): its right side has a height of 2, while its left side is empty:

```
                         ___62___
                        /        \
                     __44__      78*
                    /      \       \
                   17      50      88
                     \    /  \       \
                     42  48  54       90
```

So, this will not stay like that: a simple left rotation will move 88 up, and 78 down:

```
                         ___62___
                        /        \
                     __44__      88
                    /      \    /  \
                   17      50  78  90
                     \    /  \    
                     42  48  54
```

You had it correct for `delete(62)`: that will swap the root with its successor, which is 78, and then 62 is removed:

```
                         ___78___
                        /        \
                     __44__      88
                    /      \       \
                   17      50      90
                     \    /  \    
                     42  48  54
```

`insert(92)` will bring an unbalance at node 88:

```
                         ___78___
                        /        \
                     __44__      88*
                    /      \       \
                   17      50      90
                     \    /  \       \
                     42  48  54      92
```

And so a simple left rotation is again applied:

```
                         ___78___
                        /        \
                     __44__      90
                    /      \    /  \
                   17      50  88  92
                     \    /  \       
                     42  48  54
```

`delete(50)` was correctly executed. Given the above state, we get:

```
                         ___78___
                        /        \
                     __44__      90
                    /      \    /  \
                   17      54  88  92
                     \    /         
                     42  48
```